# Can Guest Licensed Users execute DML statements?

Tags: lightning-community

I'm working on a Lightning Community & I'm working on logic for creating a Case.  When I look the Debug Log as a Guest License user, I see that their DML limit is set to 0.

```
21:02:58.198 (4198152743)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 3 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 6 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 1 out of 0 ******* CLOSE TO LIMIT
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 268 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 1 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10
```

I am able to create cases with this user using standard components (like **lightning-record-edit-form**).  Does this DML limit mean that I will be unable to also create cases via an Apex **Database.Insert()**?

Would I be able to work around this if I run the Apex class in System Mode (in other words, have the class disregard Sharing Rules)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will see a DML Limit of 0 in Apex if the class has been defined to be cacheable.

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static void myApexClass(){}
```

To work around this limitation, you need to [set cacheable to false, but this means that you won't be able use **@wire** to invoke the method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.apex) (see the **Enable Client-Side Caching** section of the **Lightning Web Components Developer Guide**).

To see an example of a wire method being invoked imperatively, check out [the **createRecord** method in this example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.data_salesforce_write).

Answer (score 0):

Yes Site Guest user can create a Case. Check that might happen if you work with component where you need to allow DML in attributes.
Check also object permissions for Site Guest user

Answer (score 0):

You would be able to create case record using  Site guest user. Please make sure that you include the apex class in Guest user profile and also provide create permission in object level.